# Creating file geodatabase feature class without system fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, fields-attributes, file-geodatabase, feature-class

Is there a way to create a feature class without the **SHAPE_LENGTH** and **SHAPE_AREA**?

Only way I seem to be able to do this is to create a new feature class by right clicking fgdb> New > Feature Class but that is not the same as ArcPy CreateFeatureclass_management. I am trying to create feature classes programmatically using Create Feature Class (arcpy CreateFeatureclass_management) and using a template which does not have **SHAPE_LENGTH** and **SHAPE_AREA** fields but when it is created it adds the two fields. Even when I don't use template, the output has the two fields unlike the manual process. The objective is to have output schema matching that of the template (not just hiding those two added fields) but it seems like that is not possible because of the addition of **SHAPE_LENGTH** and **SHAPE_AREA**. I have tried importing workspace xml documents and the same thing happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot delete the field using tools in arcmap.

Comment: Those computed columns don't really exist on the table, but they are exposed when a geometry column is present.

Comment: @Vince I'd like to improve my answer by incorporating your comment.  I'd be happy to see you do that instead (or write another answer) if you have time to.

Answer (score 3):

A file geodatabase feature class always has the system created and system maintained fields for storing each feature’s area and length.

You cannot create one which does not have them using ArcGIS Desktop or any other software and you cannot delete those fields either.

Comment: Why is a feature class made without the shape_length and shape_area when i manually create the feature class then? The behavior is strange that it is not consistent.

Comment: I’m not at a laptop to test but I suspect they are there but not being displayed on the creation wizard.

Comment: If the creation wizard has completed and you open attributes for the feature class then do you see them?

Comment: You are right it looks like it wasnt complete doing the wizard because after closing out and looking again they do have the fields.... I wonder since original feature classes i want to use as templates were made using OGR2OGR there is something different in configuration or methodology difference in approach taken to create a feature class.

Comment: The file geodatabase format is proprietary, but accessible via the open File GDB API. If ogr2ogr is not using that then it’s templates may not be in file geodatabase format, just something that looks like it.